# What is the approximate bandwidth used for first sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, parity, bandwith

I began syncing the ethereum blockchain the other day and to my horror 2GB had downloaded with no sign of stopping. I've very limited bandwidth, so I cancelled the sync. **Does anyone know how much bandwidth the first sync usually takes?**

I was using `geth --fast` to do the sync. Would the bandwidth usage have been different if I had used parity with `--warp`?

Comment: This is a moving target because it is growing day by day. The previosly linked question gives you an idea with numbers for different operation modes. There is no point in opening another question.